# Why is Frame.Width and Frame.Height returning very incorrect values

Tags: java, image, jframe, height, width

I want to display images according to the frame and width of the JFrame such that the images will display proportionally according to the size of the Frame (my program is designed such that it is impossible to use any of the Layout managers).

However, when I try and display images according to    frame.width and    frame.height parameters, it keeps displaying the images at the top left of the JFrame. Also, print statements that include frame.width and frame.height return values of 1 and 2, respectively. How is this possible? I have put the code below.

(Also, I am sorry for the strange indentation, but I am having a lot of difficulty getting the code to display properly on this site. I have to manually press the spacebar of some lines 4 times even though I know it was the correct indentation in my code, and when I do that, it displays in the code view but with incorrect indentation).

```
public class ExperimentGame extends JPanel{

Image image;

public ExperimentGame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(500,500); //my edit
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("spaceship (0).png"));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    System.out.println(Frame.WIDTH + " " + Frame.HEIGHT);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, Frame.WIDTH, Frame.HEIGHT, null);
}
}

public class ExperimentMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExperimentGame game = new ExperimentGame();
}
}
```

Comment: `Frame.WIDTH`? Why are you even using that? And what are you trying to achieve with this code? Some image links would be nice. This is not how you display proportional width images by the way.

Comment: Read my description above, and you will see.

Comment: `public static final int WIDTH = 1;` and `public static final int HEIGHT = 2;` are flags used in the `imageUpdate` method, pretty sure they aren't doing what you think they are - This is where reading the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) becomes very imporant

Answer (score 0):

What you call is a static field of ImageObserver which indicates that the width of the base image is now available and can be taken what you want is

```
 System.out.println(frame.getWidth() + " " + frame.getHeight());
```

Notice i call method of a frame object not static fields of Frame class

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. However, when I made the change I am still getting the exact same result.

Comment: Did you also changed this line g.drawImage(image, Frame.WIDTH, Frame.HEIGHT, null);

Comment: Wait, I didn't change the code properly and now it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Always happy to help

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this